# Swift 5 Calling GameOver method simultaneously from two methods crashing game

Tags: swift, physics, contacts, simultaneous

I am learning to code and learning off a "Color switch" tutorial. I have tried to strengthen my knowledge and have created 2 switches and balls falling.

I am having issues once the balls come in contact with the switches. I have a did begin contact method for both switches and if wrong, calls the gameOver method. But when both switches are wrong they both call the gameOver method simultaneously resulting in my game to crash. How can I solve this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Current code:

```
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.switchCategory {
        if let ball = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Ball" ? contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode {
            if currentColourIndex == switchState.rawValue {
                score += 1
                updateScoreLabel()
                ball.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.15)) {
                    ball.removeFromParent()
                    self.spawnBall()
                }
            } else {
                gameOver()
            }
        }
    }

    let contactMask2 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if contactMask2 == PhysicsCategories2.ballCategory2 | PhysicsCategories2.switchCategory2 {
        if let ball2 = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Ball2" ? contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode {
            if currentColourIndex2 == switchState2.rawValue {
                score += 1
                updateScoreLabel()
                ball2.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.15)) {
                    ball2.removeFromParent()
                    self.spawnBall2()
                }
            } else {
                gameOver()
            }
        }
    }


}


}


func gameOver() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "RecentScore")
    if score > UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Highscore") {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    let menuScene = MenuScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
    view!.presentScene(menuScene)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is that it is not simultaneous.  It is called twice, but one at a time.

So, to solve it, just add code to `gameOver()` such that a second call is ignored.  For example.

```
var gameIsOver = false

func gameOver() {
    guard !gameIsOver else { return }
    gameIsOver = true

    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "RecentScore")
    if score > UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Highscore") {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    let menuScene = MenuScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
    view!.presentScene(menuScene)
}
```

If you reuse this object, you need to reset `gameIsOver` back to false.

Another way to solve it is to make it safe to call more than once.  Perhaps `view` is nil in the second call.

You should never use `view!` if you can help it.  A better approach is

```
guard let view = view else { return }
```

At the beginning. If view is nil, the function will immediately return.  In the rest the function you can use `view.bounds` or `view.presentScene` because view can't be nil after the guard.